# Подскажите какое-нибудь готовое решение angularjs для отправки email через ajax + php mail()

Tags: php, angularjs

HTML

```
<form id="form-cb"class="uk-form callback"method="post"action>
    <h2>Заказать обратный звонок</h2>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" name="name" required="required">
    <input type="tel" placeholder="Номер телефона" name="phone" required="required">
    <textarea name="comment" placeholder="Комментарий" required="required"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
 if((isset($_POST['name'])&&$_POST['name']!="")&&(isset($_POST['phone'])&&$_POST['phone']!="")&&(isset($_POST['comment'])&&$_POST['comment']!="")){ //Проверка отправилось ли наше поля name и не пустые ли они
     $to = 'anymail@gmail.com'; //Почта получателя, через запятую можно указать сколько угодно адресов
     $subject = 'Заголовок сообщения';
     $message = '
         <html>
            <head>
               <title>'.$subject.'</title>
            </head>
            <body>
               <p>Имя: '.$_POST['name'].'</p>
               <p>Телефон: '.$_POST['phone'].'</p>                        
               <p>Комментарий: '$_POST['comment'].'</p>
             </body>
         </html>'; //Текст нащего сообщения можно использовать HTML теги
     $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"; //Кодировка письма
     $headers .= "From: Отправитель <from@example.com>\r\n"; //Наименование и почта отправителя
     mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); //Отправка письма с помощью функции mail
    }
?>
```

Comment: ангуляр тут совсем не причем, отправка почты - это серверное решение. Ну а передавать данные нужно как и при любых `ajax` запросах. А отправку запроса осуществлять через `$http` ангуляра

Comment: @Василий Барбашев так я и  имел ввиду, как правильно написать в контроллере имея два этих примера

Comment: дак обычный `ajax` запрос, с параметрами типа `имя`, `телефон`, `комментарий`. Читай доки если не умеешь делать стандартный запрос.